# Google Maps inside a tab goes blurry after switching tabs a few times

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, bootstrap-modal

I initialize 2 google maps inside of different tabs in a bootstrap modal popup.

The maps are initialized on shown event of the tab, and the maps are displayed correctly. There is a polygon of a field displayed correctly in the center of the maps.

After switching tabs multiple times, the map displays with the background blurred, but with the polygon still rendered correctly.

Once the maps have been rendered, I trigger the window resize event using the following code:

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

It seems that the map sometimes refreshes correctly when switching back and forth between tabs, but only temporarily.

This functionality has worked for some time without problems, and has recently begun to show these symptoms.

Does anyone know if this is as a result of a google maps update? Or any ideas on how to refresh the map?

Thanks

I have tried delaying this call:

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

with a setTimeout, and also tried firing the resize event on the map itself using:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); //I have read that this call is now retired.
```

I have tried setting the zoom level for the map after a tab is shown.

I am building a codepen at the moment, but am having trouble with google maps there too ;(

I expect to be able to switch tabs as many times as I like without the google map going blurry or getting re-centered or zoomed in/out.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed - the issue was being caused by code that used to correct the problem of the map loosing position when hidden and shown by moving to a different tab:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); //I have read that this call is now retired.
```

and

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

Removing these calls fixed the issue.